# FreeBSD or NetBSD based commercial TCP/IP stack vendor?

Tags: tcp, freebsd

Receiving recommendations for commercial TCP/IP stack implementation based on FreeBSD or NetBSD. Requirements are similar to a typical desktop PC running a browser, email and streaming voice/video. Which is to say a rich network functionality for a end-host type of device with mature implementation and reasonable performance.

BSD derived network stacks are deployed in wide variety of situations for years and hence have mature implementation.

It's supposed to run on a proprietary RTOS.

Most vendors I found don't advertise if their stack is based on BSD. Any recommendations?

-- Vineet

Comment: Does it really matter if the semantics is the same?

Answer (score 0):

It's not commercial, but you could take a look at OSkit. It uses FreeBSD's networking stack. It might be easier to take the stack out of OSkit than from FreeBSD
http://www.cs.utah.edu/flux/oskit/